# ADO's Command object Error when adAsyncExecute

Tags: c++, oledb, ado

I'm using ADO's Command object to execute simple commands.

For example,

```
_CommandPtr CommPtr;
CommPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
CommPtr->ActiveConnection = MY_CONNECTION;
CommPtr->CommandType = adCmdText;
CommPtr->CommandText = L"insert into MY_TABLE values MY_VALUE";

for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    CommPtr->Execute(NULL, NULL, adExecuteNoRecords);
}
```

This works fine, yet I wanted to make this an asynchronus execution to enhance performance when dealing with large amount of data... So I just simply changed the Execute Option to adAsyncExecute..

([Documentation Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
_CommandPtr CommPtr;
CommPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
CommPtr->ActiveConnection = MY_CONNECTION;
CommPtr->CommandType = adCmdText;
CommPtr->CommandText = L"insert into MY_TABLE values MY_VALUE";

for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    CommPtr->Execute(NULL, NULL, adAsyncExecute);
}
```

This gives me a memory error for some reason..

```
First-change exception
Microsoft C++ exception:
_com_error at memory location 0x0028FA24
```

Any experts on ADO know why this is happening..?

Thanks

Comment: That isn't how `adAsynchExecute` is used, and the documentation you linked makes no indications whatsoever that it is. Asynch execution sets up connection point notifications that can be monitored. It doesn't mean you can fire-and-forget as you appear to believe you can.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks.. is there an example of how adAsynchExecute is supposed to be used?

Comment: Honestly its the wrong approach to begin with. I think you're better off generating a script to perform your insertions in *batches*, then submit that in a divisor loop. I see nothing preventing you from scripting *multiple* `INSERT` statements per round-trip to the SQL server. Ex: script 200 `INSERT`s and make 50 round trips rather than 10,000. (the benefit of a reduced T-log hit would be a bonus, btw). Try that and see if it is more satisfactory for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not bother ask why you need to loop 10K times just to execute the query as it would take you tremendous network, client and server resources.

I will answer how to use the Asynchronous way of executing queries.
You use this style of query execution to prevent your client from having a stuck-up GUI.

To the user, your App has hanged while it is waiting for the reply of your query. Your App cannot do anything. It looks frozen while waiting for a reply from the Database Server.

To implement a nice GUI with animated Hourglass to work, just like below:

[image]

you need to execute the query in Asynch mode.

Example below written in Visual Basic:

```
dbCon.Execute "Insert Into ...Values....",,adAsyncExecute
Do While dbCon.State = (ADODB.ObjectStateEnum.adStateExecuting + ADODB.ObjectStateEnum.adStateOpen)
   Application.DoEvents
Loop
```

This way, the client will continue to wait and permit the GUI to do some events while it is waiting for the reply of the server making your App more responsive.